# closing an RPC server endpoint

Tags: c++, c, rpc, endpoint

I have a program that starts an RPC server with a specific port:

1. RpcServerRegisterIf
2. RPCServerUseProtSeqEp
3. start listening...
4. RpcUnregisterIf

However, immediately after calling RPCServerUseProtSeqEp the port is assigned to the process and subsequent calls to this function returns Duplicate Endpoint.

How can I unregister\close this port? I need to use this rpc server in several processes.

Comment: See this answer [“endpoint is a duplicate” when starting an RPC server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746702/endpoint-is-a-duplicate-when-starting-an-rpc-server).
Good luck

Comment: I looked at it already, it does not solve the problem

Answer (score -1):

You mixed up the order:

1. RpcServerUseProtseqEp()  // tell RPC which protocol to use
2. RpcServerRegisterIf()    // register interface
3. RpcServerListen()

see [msdn, RPCServer Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378869%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I hope this answer isn't too late

add 8/22/2016

1. To close a server-endpoint use
   RpcServerUnregisterIf()
   see [msdn, Stopping RPCServer Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378687(v=vs.85).aspx)
2. again: you mixed up the order of api calls: first call RpcServerUseProtseqEp() to specify the protocol, then RpcServerRegisterIf() to register the server and then RpcServerListen()
3. RpcServerListen() is blocking the thread it is called from. If you call it from a console program use ctrl c to end the call. Then the next line of code will be executed, which will be normally RpcServerUnregisterIf(). If you called RpcServerListen() from a nseperate thread, for example in a service, shut down the server with RpcMgmtStopServerListening() in the main thread.

Comment: This does not in any way answer the question.

Comment: This still does not answer the question - how do you close the RPC endpoint (using TCP with a port number) in such a way that you can re-open it in the same process.  It looks like it may not actually be possible.

Comment: You answer outlines the order of starting a server and does not add any detail about how to shut it down and release the TCP acceptor.